# Transformation of data using proc transpose -- static column names lead to duplicate records

Tags: sas, duplicates, transpose, proc

I have the following data strucure, which I need to transform:

I have been working on transposing the data properly to obtain a table structure.

Target structure

```
Attribute 1, Attribute 2, ...., Attribute n

Outcome1-A, Outcome2-A, ...., Outcome n-A .....

....

Outcome A-Z, Outcome2-Z, ...., Outcome n-Z .....
```

I started with the following statement,  modifications would be great. The static names of the attributes are imported as duplicate records.

```
    PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=INPUT_TAB OUT=vertikal ;
    VAR v  name ;
    id n;
    RUN;
```

Comment: Do you want to use the value of NAME as the names of the new variables?  Are any of the values longer than 32 bytes?  If so then you will need to create a new variable with a shorter value that you could use as the name for the new variables.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` statement serves tels SAS which variable to use for column names, and if I understand your question well, that is `Name`, not `n`. Hence `Name` should not be in the `VAR` list

You should also tell SAS when to start a new observation (aka row), using a `by` statement. Probably one of the columns left of `Name` is a good candidate. Let's name it `group_id`. Hence the code should look like this:

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=INPUT_TAB OUT=vertikal ;
   by group_id;
   VAR v;
   id Name;
RUN;
```

If there is no variable like `group_id` available, you can create one this way:

```
DATA INPUT_VIEW / view=INPUT_VIEW;
   set INPUT_TAB;
   retain group_id 1;
   if Name eq "SZENARIO_ID" then group_id = group_id + 1;

PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=INPUT_VIEW OUT=vertikal ;
   by group_id;
   VAR v;
   id Name;
RUN;
```

I choose a view to avoid needlessly writing data to disk, but that only matters for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I expanded the table using COL_TYP, however the transpose command does not work, see error message

```
PROC SQL; 
  CREATE TABLE TEST_CASE_WHEN AS 
  SELECT A.*,
         CASE WHEN A.NAME IN ('SZENARIO_ID') THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END AS COL_TYP
  FROM   WORK.TEST A
 ;
QUIT;


proc sort 
data = work.INPUT_VIEW out= input_view2;
BY N;
RUN; 



PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=INPUT_VIEW2 OUT=vertikal ;
   by COL_TYP;
   VAR v;
   id Name;
RUN;
```

ERROR: Data set WORK.INPUT_VIEW2 is not sorted in ascending sequence. The current BY group has
COL_TYP = 2 and the next BY group has COL_TYP = 0.

Thanks and Kind Regards
Kingsley

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You told SAS the data was sorted by COL_TYP and it is not.  Change the BY statement in the sort step to match the BY statement n the transpose step.  Please update your question with actual sample data that reproduces the issue. Not photographs of the data, actual text.